# Conemu slow paste

Tags: conemu

Former mac user here that is being forced to switch to windows.  I really loved Iterm2 on the mac, and have found Conemu to be a satisfactory replacement.  One feature I really miss though is the paste slowly option in Iterm2.  This really helps to prevent outrunning config pastes in some of my Cisco routers.  Is there anyway to add/turn on this feature?

Comment: I love conemu, but I find the paste-related slowness problematic as well. https://hyper.is/ is a node.js-based cross-platform console and pasting into remote sessions via hyper is as fast as it was under Mac and iTerm. Check it out. A better answer is to have ConEmu be as fast as Hyper, since I’d rather not load a session merely to paste large snippets of text. ConEmu does offer four types of paste, including “Multiline” and “single line” It seems “Multiline” should suffice, but despite using it, I don’t see a gain in time to return the console after a paste.

Comment: Filed a new issue about thet: https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/1361